# Cordova Http Plugin: postJSON not a function

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to use the cordova-HTTP plugin. Whenever I try to make a call to the postJSON() method, I get error as

```
LOG: [ERR] TypeError: cordovaHTTP.postJSON is not a function. (In 'cordovaHTTP.postJSON', 'cordovaHTTP.postJSON' is undefined)
```

Steps that I followed to install the plugin:

1. created cordova project
2. `cordova platform add ios`
3. `cordova plugin add https://github.com/brendonparker/cordova-HTTP.git`
4. Now since I do not have apple-pc, so instead I make use of Evothings Workbench to build the app by dragg-dropping the index.html file in the workbench. Then I clicked on RUN to run the app. This produces the error in the 'tools' windows of workbench.

Also, the call to postJSON method is made just after 'deviceReady'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [that method](https://github.com/brendonparker/cordova-HTTP/blob/master/src/android/com/synconset/CordovaHTTP/CordovaHttpPostJson.java) is called `postJson`, not `postJSON`.

Here's an example of how to use it ([copy-pasted from here](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP/pull/50)):

```
var dto = {
    description: 'sending a plain old javascript object',
    child: {
        foo: 'bar',
    }
};

cordovaHTTP.postJson('https://some-server/api/', dto, { }, function(response) {
        // prints 200
        console.log(response.status);
        try {
            // response.data has already been parsed
            //response.data = JSON.parse(response.data);

            // prints test
            console.log(response.data.message);
        } catch(e) {
            console.error('JSON parsing error');
        }
    }, function(response) {
        // prints 403
        console.log(response.status);

        //prints Permission denied 
        console.log(response.error);
    });
```

Update:
If using Evothings, the plugin must be added into the 'evothings' source code itself and then rebuild the app.

Comment: i tried the same. Still give me the same error.
It seems somehow it is not taking the "modified" version of the plugin. Because 'post' method works but 'postJson' does not

Comment: Looking at [`package.json` in the "modified" version](https://github.com/brendonparker/cordova-HTTP/blob/master/package.json), I see it's still pointing to the original `cordova-HTTP` package repository, which might explain why you're getting the unmodified version (without `postJson`) when you use `cordova plugin add`. Can you manually download & add the  modified version?

Comment: Try `cordova plugin add https://github.com/rphv/cordova-HTTP.git` - I forked brendonparker's fork and updated `package.json` to point to the "modified" version.

Comment: You are correct. I re-read the documentation and understood that the 'evothings viewer' app itself must be modified to include the new plugin. A simple inclusion in the custom apps built via evothings would not work.
Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome - please consider an upvote if this helped.